# onBackPressed always return to WebView not activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, methods, android-webview, back-button

I have a WebView on my Fragment. But, i want to call a method on "onBackPressed()", not calling goBack my WebView. When i hit back button, my WebView always return to previous page, not calling my method at all.

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myTag") != null) {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack())
           //myWebView.goBack();
        }else {
          super.onBackPressed();
          saveAllData();
        }
    }else{
       super.onBackPressed();
       saveAllData();
    }
 }
```

I have try different way, but it doesn't work, see below :
**edit 1 :**

On my Fragment1 :

```
 public void backButtonWasPressed() {
      saveAllData();
 }
```

On my Activity :

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();
      FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
      TopicFragment fragment1 = (TopicFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
      fragment1.backButtonWasPressed();
 }
```

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: you should put `saveAllData()` in `onPause` thats the way to do it.

Comment: but how is it works onBackPressed()? that i want is when user hit backbutton on the device, then saveAllData() execute.

Answer (score 0):

it's happening because you are adding the fragment to backstack. so before commiting the fragment transaction add this code

```
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

example:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: i have addToBackStack(null) and even if i not use BackStack. My WebView still focused, and when i hit backbutton, my WebView return to previous page.

Comment: i have alternate code, see my edit 1 above. And still doesn't work.